# PubNub subscribe error

Tags: python-3.x, networking, raspberry-pi3, pubnub

**UPDATE: It seems turning on SSL resolved the problem. I am currently monitoring the system to see if the issue returns.**

We are encountering the following error when we attempt to subscribe to a feed on a specific network. We have about 40 devices running pubnub with the same code and only one of them is encountering this issue so we believe it is something to do with the specific network it is running on. I was wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue in the past and or had any idea of what may be causing it.

Error

```
Async request Exception. Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) 
Exception in subscribe loop: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Connection Code

```
pnconfig=PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = XXX
pnconfig.publish_key = XXX
pnconfig.ssl = False
pnconfig.reconnect_policy=PNReconnectionPolicy.LINEAR 
pubnub_obj=PubNub(pnconfig)
pubnub_obj.add_listener(process_message(log))
pubnub_obj.subscribe().channels(str(log.getPubnubTabletId())).execute()
```

Comment: Nice yes this is always best to set `ssl=True` / `secure=True` on the SDK.

Comment: Trent - you can answer your own question on this thread to earn more points.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling TLS (SSL) will prevent ISPs from *traffic shaping* resulting in Gateway Timeouts among other issues.

```
pnconfig=PNConfiguration()
pnconfig.subscribe_key = XXX
pnconfig.publish_key = XXX
pnconfig.ssl = True // <<<<< enable TLS (this is default in latest SDKs)
pubnub_obj=PubNub(pnconfig)
```